# Moving QMessageBox?

Tags: c++, qt, qmessagebox

Basically I'm learning the basics of Qt C++ and I'm trying to open up two different `QMessageBox`'s at the same time but they overlap each other. I was wondering if it was possible to have them side by side. Any input on how to do so would be greatly appreciated.

Extra information: I'm opening them by using the `QMessageBox::name(this,"Title", "Text")` way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QMessageBox::move(int x, int y)` to place the message box where you want on the screen. You can also use `QMessageBox::setGeometry(int x, int y, int width, int height)`.

Answer (score 1):

That does not really make sense. `QMessageBox` is not for arbitrary windows, but specifically for [modal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_dialog) dialogs. The user cannot interact with two modal dialogs. Anyway, I don't see anything in the documentation that would allow you to align message boxes or set coordinates etc.

Edit: As Marian noted, there is the `move` method of `QWidget`. This might work, but I would not recommend it. Modal dialogs are usually not presented side by side. This might confuse the user.

If you really need two windows side by side, non-modal (custom) windows or dock widgets might be a better solution.